# Magento2: Do we need to run set up upgrade command each time to see any changes?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, log

I have created an observer `controller_action_predispatch` that should call on each time page load.

Its working fine but only for the first time page load. After that i have to run command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` to make it work again.

This doesn't seems correct.

**events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="akhil_event_observer_eachpageload" instance="Akhil\Event\Observer\EachPageLoad" />
</event>
</config>
```

**EachPageLoad.php**

```
<?php
namespace Akhil\Event\Observer;

use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

 class EachPageLoad implements ObserverInterface
{

protected $logger;


   public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $this->logger->warn('PAGE Loaded..!!');
}
}
```

Comment: You should post your Observer here.

Comment: okay, added observer code.

Comment: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` will only run installation and upgrade scripts I don't see how it's related to your problem.

Comment: @JulienLachal That command also clears the cache, which probably *is* related to OP's problem ;-)

Comment: @DanielSloof good point, I didn't see that.

Comment: If same page i refresh multiple times then it doesn't add log entry again & again but when new page loads then it does. So its okay i guess.

Comment: Just one info i required basically when we need to run the setup upgrade command, i mean which file(Models,Helpers templates, xml etc) changes required to run setup upgrade.